# Extrair tags do XML C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml

Consegui pegar uma tag, mas não achei uma forma de pegar uma tag que se repita e armazenar cada repetição em uma lista.

Exemplo XML

```
<casa>
  <porta>
     <janela>Janela 1</janela>
     <janela>Janela 2</janela>
     <janela>Janela 2</janela>
  </porta>
</casa>
```

Código atual de exemplo:

```
 var retorno = (from nota in xmlRetorno.Elements()
                       where nota.Name.LocalName.Equals("porta")
                       select nota).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode criar uma classe contendo as propriedades do seu objeto para depois usar a classe de `Deserialize` onde ele vai pegar as informações do XML e converter diretamente para o seu objeto. Deste modo o seu código fica mais limpo, e de fácil manutenção.

Você pode ver exemplos da própria comunidade a respeito dessa classe nos links:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364253/how-to-deserialize-xml-document

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035637/xml-deserialization?rq=1

Um código de deserialize genérico que eu construi apenas demonstrando como funciona:

XML Exemplo:

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<CLIENTE>
 <ROW>
  <TABELA>CLIENTE</TABELA>
  <DATA_RECADASTRO/>
  <ID_CLIENTE>10262202</ID_CLIENTE>
  <ID_CLIENTE_RECADASTRO/>
  <NOME_CLIENTE>CLIENTE EXEMPLO 1</NOME_CLIENTE>
  <TIPO_CLIENTE>FIS</TIPO_CLIENTE>
 </ROW>
 <ROW>
  <TABELA>CLIENTE</TABELA>
  <DATA_RECADASTRO>20/03/2018</DATA_RECADASTRO>
  <ID_CLIENTE>10450769</ID_CLIENTE>
  <ID_CLIENTE_RECADASTRO/>
  <NOME_CLIENTE>CLIENTE EXEMPLO 2</NOME_CLIENTE>
  <TIPO_CLIENTE>FIS</TIPO_CLIENTE>
 </ROW>
 </CLIENTE>
```

```js
public static T DeserializeObject<T>(string xml)
             where T : class
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(xml))
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Empty XML ERROR");

    using (var stringReader = new StringReader(xml))
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        return (T)serializer.Deserialize(stringReader);
    }
}
```

Note que a classe objeto que você está passando para o método deve conter as `DataNotations` referentes a cada tag contida no XML para o Deserialize fazer a conversão. Exemplo:

```js
[Serializable]
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "ROW")]
    public class ClientInfo
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "TABELA")]
        public string NomeTabela { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ID_CLIENTE", Type = typeof(int))]
        public int ClienteID { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ID_CLIENTE_RECADASTRO")]
        public string ClientIDRecadastro { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "NOME_CLIENTE")]
        public string NomeCliente { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "TIPO_CLIENTE")]
        public string TipoCliente { get; set; }

        [XmlIgnore]
        public DateTime DataRecadastro { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("DATA_RECADASTRO")]
        public string SomeDateString
        {
            get { return this.DataRecadastro.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"); }
            set {
                if (value != "")
                    this.DataRecadastro = DateTime.Parse(value);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Para pegar as tags precisa deserializar? Não entendi, mas se o Raul marcou como reposta deve ter feito sentido no contexto dele e aí talvez eu que não entendi a pergunta rsrs.

Comment: Exatamente, para pegar as tags em um XML essa classe te auxilia a ter acesso a cada elemento e trabalhar diretamente com uma classe de propriedades.

Answer (score 2):

Para pegar os elementos do XML você pode usar LINQ-to-XML, fiz um exemplo em um Console application usando seu XML e ficou assim:

```
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Xml;
    using System.Xml.Linq;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        string xml = @"<casa>
                      <porta>
                         <janela>Janela 1</janela>
                         <janela>Janela 2</janela>
                         <janela>Janela 2</janela>
                      </porta>
                    </casa>";

        XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
        var descendantsQuery = from desc in xDoc.Root.Descendants("janela")
                               select desc;

        foreach (var item in descendantsQuery)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Na linha `var descendantsQuery = from desc in xDoc.Root.Descendants("janela")` estamos informando que a partir do elemento raiz (*xDoc.Root* que no seu XML é "porta") queremos obter os descendentes (*xDoc.Root.Descendants*) cujo nome é "janela".

Comment: só trocaria a linha em que se obtém o resultado para obter uma lista conforme é colocado.

var descendantsQuery = from desc in xDoc.Root.Descendants("janela")
                               select desc;

 
`List<string> descendantsQuery = new List<string>() from desc in xDoc.Root.Descendants("janela")
                               select desc;`